# What computational model supports arbitrarily sized integers?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, integers, primes, factoring

I want to do some research, but I don't think it's important the number of bits it takes to represent the integer input and arithmetic on the abstract machine.  So what is the model that addresses this?

Specifically, I want to prove that integer factorization is not in P.  If the above is a bad idea, then what model should I be using?  Clearly, I would be needing add, sub, mul, and divide instructions.

Or, should something else be used such as algebraic complexity theory?

Comment: Found this paper: https://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/ChenKaWi2011.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for either the RAM model or the [transdichotomous model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transdichotomous_model).  They differ primarily in how they take into account the size of integers and their effect on the time of various operations.  See [What's the difference between transdichotomous model and RAM?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/90974/whats-the-difference-between-transdichotomous-model-and-ram).

If you want your results to have any applicability at all, the main thing is to pick a model that avoids treating the time to do arithmetic on exponential-length integers as polynomial, otherwise you can end up with absurd results.  If you count each arithmetic operation as $O(1)$ time, no matter how large the numbers are, then you end up with absurd results like polynomial-time algorithms for factoring and indeed all of #PSPACE.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/53885/755.

Note that proving a problem is in P is not the same as proving it runs in polynomial time on some strange model of computation.  P is defined as problems that have an algorithm that run in polynomial time *on a Turing machine*.  As mentioned in the previous paragraph, if you change "on a Turing machine" to some other model of computation, that statement might no longer hold.

It's a famous open problem with factorization is in P or not. The problem is likely to be very difficult, with our current state of understanding.  I would not recommend taking on such an ambitious goal.